# What is the cron file of three times per month, from 3-5 pm?

Tags: cron

I want to run a job three times per month from 3-5 pm.

Hence, I should add a line to `/etc/crontab` which satisfy those needs.

How do I add this line known that I try the following, and it seems not correct:

```
0 15-17 1,10,20 3 * /home/kia/publish.sh
```

Comment: That will run nine times in March. For three times per month, either pick one time on three days in every month, or three times on one day in every month.

Comment: "three times per month". Did you mean "three times per day on 3 days in each month"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition is correct, if the job is to run only in March, 3 times a day and on day 1, 10 and 20.

If not, use e.g.

```
0 15 1,10,20 * * /home/kia/publish.sh
```

to start at 3pm on day 1,10 and 20 or

```
0 15-17 1 * * /home/kia/publish.sh
```

to start on the first day each month at 3pm, 4pm and 5pm

And to change the crontab file, use the command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: Same comment: this is 9 times ;)  day 1, 10, 20 at 15, 16 and 17 each = 9